# How to set a single field to use Email or Phone validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using [jquery-validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin to perform client side validation, what I'm trying to accomplish is to give a single input the rules for email or phone number based on another input.

If the second input has the value for "email" then the rule for email is set true and the rule for phoneNumber is set to false and visceversa.

The problem I'm facing is that no matter what I do, the validation always asks for a valid e-mail address.

I'm not using the built in rules for email or phone, I made some of my own, here they are:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod( "phoneNumber", function( phone_number, element ) {
            return this.optional( element ) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
                phone_number.match( /^[0-9]{7}|[0-9]{10}|\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{7}|\([0-9]{3}\)[\s\-]{1}[0-9]{3}[\s\-]{1}[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{3}[\s\-]{1}[0-9]{3}[\s\-]{1}[0-9]{4}$/ );
        }, 'Enter a valid phone number');

jQuery.validator.addMethod( "emailAddress", function( email, element ) {
            return this.optional( element ) ||
                email.match( /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/ );
        }, 'Enter a valid e-mail address');
```

The way I'm assigning the rules is:

```
$(`#input1`).rules('add', {
     required: function(element) {
          if($(`#input2`).val() != '') return true;

          return false;
     },
     emailAddress: function(element) {
          if($(`#input2`).val() == 'email') return true;

          return false;
     },
     phoneNumber: function(element) {
          if($(`#input2`).val() == 'phone') return true;

          return false;
     }
});
```

So, the field is only required when the `input2` has some value (working good), but no matter what option I select on `input2` the validation always fail with 'Enter a valid e-mail address'.

I expect that when `input2` has the value "email" the validation fails with 'Enter a valid e-mail address' and when the value for `input2` is "phone" then fails with 'Enter a valid phone number'.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the relevant HTML markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are completely swapping out the rules, I would write a handler that dynamically adds and removes the rules as needed.

```
$('#input2').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'phone') {
        $('#input1').rules('remove', 'emailAddress');
        $('#input1').rules('add', {
            phoneNumber: true
        });
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 'email') {
        $('#input1').rules('remove', 'phoneNumber')
        $('#input1').rules('add', {
            emailAddress: true
        });
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/gk0e372j/](https://jsfiddle.net/gk0e372j/)**

However, when nothing is typed into the `#input2` field, the phone/email field (`#field1`) is still `required` and will accept anything, so you still need to decide how you want to handle that part, like what is your default position.  Otherwise, you have shown no HTML and not explained why you are using `.rules()` to declare these.

---

Here is the same logic except it's declaring everything within the `.validate()` method and using the `depends` option.

```
$('#myform').validate({ 
    rules: {
        input1: {
            required: true,
            phoneNumber: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return ($('#input2').val() === 'phone') ? true : false;
                }
            },
            emailAddress: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return ($('#input2').val() === 'email') ? true : false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**DEMO 2:  [jsfiddle.net/wnpxh9cm/](https://jsfiddle.net/wnpxh9cm/)**

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using something like this.. the reason that I'm using the `.rules("add", ...)` method is because those inputs are beign generated dynamically and are not part of the original HTML markup. 

Thanks again. I will aslo try the `depends` rule, didn't know about it.